# Changing default terminal in Krusader file manager

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, terminator, krusader

I am using Krusader as my file manager. And I wanted to know if there is anyway that I can change the default Konsole terminal to Terminator in the Krusader file manager.

My Linux distribution is Kubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install terminator`?

Comment: Yes, I had done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching I found that you can fix this by going to Settings>>configure Krusader>>General>>enter terminator in the blank next to External Terminal. Then after that again go to Settings>>configure Krusader>>User Actions>>enter terminator in the blank next to terminal for UserActions. That is how to change the default terminal in Krusader file manager.